# Using ggvis layer_histogram in shiny app generates error for empty data.frame

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, ggvis

I would like to plot a stacked histogram using `ggvis` in a shiny app from a filter-able set of data.

When the filters return an empty `data.frame`, I would like to have an empty plot displayed.

The following works as expected with a "non-stacked" histogram:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  library(shiny)
  library(ggvis)
  library(dplyr)

  data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

    diamonds_sub <- reactive({
      d <- diamonds
      if (input$CLARITY != "All") {
        d <- d %>% filter(clarity == input$CLARITY)
      }
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      d
    })

    hist_standard <- reactive({
      diamonds_sub %>%
        filter(cut == "Ideal") %>%
        ggvis(x=~price) %>%
        layer_histograms()
    })

    hist_standard %>% bind_shiny("hist_standard")

}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Histogram test")
    ,sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("CLARITY", "Clarity"
                    ,c("All", "I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"
                       ,"Non-Existent Clarity")
        )
      )
      ,mainPanel(ggvisOutput("hist_standard"))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I select "Non-Existent Clarity" in the app, I get the following result:

[image]

My goal is to get this behavior in stacked histogram with the following code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  library(shiny)
  library(ggvis)
  library(dplyr)

  data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

    diamonds_sub <- reactive({
      d <- diamonds
      if (input$CLARITY != "All") {
        d <- d %>% filter(clarity == input$CLARITY)
      }
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      d
    })

    hist_stacked <- reactive({
      diamonds_sub %>%
        filter(cut == "Ideal") %>%
        ggvis(x=~price, prop("fill", ~color)) %>%
        group_by(color) %>%
        layer_histograms()
    })

    hist_stacked %>% bind_shiny("hist_stacked")
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Histogram test")
    ,sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("CLARITY", "Clarity"
                    ,c("All", "I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"
                       ,"Non-Existent Clarity")
        )
      )
      ,mainPanel(ggvisOutput("hist_stacked"))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Although the app will run as written, when I try to select "Non-Existent Clarity" in the "stacked" version, my app crashes with the following error and warning messages:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3062
Guessing width = 500 # range / 38
Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 10, got: 0
Error: no applicable method for 'compute_stack' applied to an object of class "function"
Warning: Error in eval: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    124: eval
    123: prop_value.prop_variable
    122: prop_value
    121: data_range
    120: <reactive>
    109: x
    108: value.reactive
    107: FUN
    106: lapply
    105: values
    104: drop_nulls
    103: concat
    102: data_range
    101: <reactive>
     90: old_domain
     89: expand_range
     88: <reactive>
     77: x
     76: value.reactive
     75: value
     74: data.frame
     73: <reactive>
     62: data_reactive
     61: as.vega
     60: session$sendCustomMessage
     59: observerFunc
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
Warning: Error in eval: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    124: eval
    123: prop_value.prop_variable
    122: prop_value
    121: data_range
    120: <reactive>
    109: x
    108: value.reactive
    107: FUN
    106: lapply
    105: values
    104: drop_nulls
    103: concat
    102: data_range
    101: <reactive>
     90: old_domain
     89: expand_range
     88: <reactive>
     77: x
     76: value.reactive
     75: value
     74: data.frame
     73: <reactive>
     62: data_reactive
     61: as.vega
     60: session$sendCustomMessage
     59: observerFunc
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'apply_props' applied to an object of class "function"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    74: apply_props
    73: <reactive>
    62: data_reactive
    61: as.vega
    60: session$sendCustomMessage
    59: observerFunc
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Warning: Error in eval: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    111: eval
    110: prop_value.prop_variable
    109: prop_value
    108: data_range
    107: <reactive>
     96: x
     95: value.reactive
     94: FUN
     93: lapply
     92: values
     91: drop_nulls
     90: concat
     89: data_range
     88: <reactive>
     77: x
     76: value.reactive
     75: value
     74: data.frame
     73: <reactive>
     62: data_reactive
     61: as.vega
     60: session$sendCustomMessage
     59: observerFunc
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'apply_props' applied to an object of class "function"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    62: <Anonymous>
    61: stop
    60: data_table[[name]]
    59: observerFunc
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

**QUESTION: How can I get the same "blank plot" behavior from a stacked histogram that I am getting from a non-stacked histogram?**

Comment: @HubertL This results in the following error: `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't a solution to what (I think) is undesirable behavior in `hist_stacked`, but it does solve my problem in a hackish sort of way...

As can be seen in the error/warning output above (`Error: no applicable method for 'compute_stack' applied to an object of class "function"` in particular), it appears that `hist_stacked` is getting hung-up when asked to "compute stacks" for an empty data.frame. Since `ggviz` will error-out by itself (i.e. before the evaluation ever makes it to `group_by`), I need to determine whether or not I have filtered to an empty data.frame before I ever start to pipe into `ggviz`.

I accomplish this by adding an additional reactive function (`diamonds_sub_dim`) to calculate the dimensions of the data.frame

```
    diamonds_sub_dim <- reactive({
      d <- diamonds
      if (input$CLARITY != "All") {
        d <- d %>% filter(clarity == input$CLARITY)
      }
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      dim(d)
    })
```

I then make use of this function inside an if-else statement within the `hist_stacked` function as shown below. If `diamonds_sub_dim()[1]==0`, then I plot the original unstacked histogram. The fact that the data.frame is empty will get me an empty plot. Otherwise, I calculate the stacked histogram as normal.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  library(shiny)
  library(ggvis)
  library(dplyr)

  data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

    diamonds_sub <- reactive({
      d <- diamonds
      if (input$CLARITY != "All") {
        d <- d %>% filter(clarity == input$CLARITY)
      }
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      d
    })

    diamonds_sub_dim <- reactive({
      d <- diamonds
      if (input$CLARITY != "All") {
        d <- d %>% filter(clarity == input$CLARITY)
      }
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      dim(d)
    })

    hist_stacked <- reactive({

      if (diamonds_sub_dim()[1]==0) {
        diamonds_sub() %>%
          filter(cut == "Ideal") %>%
          ggvis(x=~price) %>%
          layer_histograms()
      } else {
        diamonds_sub() %>%
          filter(cut == "Ideal") %>%
          ggvis(x=~price, prop("fill", ~color)) %>%
          group_by(color) %>%
          layer_histograms()
      }
    })
    hist_stacked %>% bind_shiny("hist_stacked")
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Histogram test")
    ,sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("CLARITY", "Clarity"
                    ,c("All", "I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"
                       ,"Non-Existent Clarity")
        )
      )
      ,mainPanel(ggvisOutput("hist_stacked")
                 )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I will happily accept a more elegant answer should anyone have a suggestion.

Comment: A bit more elegant ; `diamonds_sub_dim <- reactive(dim(diamonds_sub()))`